# "Outfile disabled" MySQL Error

Tags: mysql

Hola estoy tratando de crear un nuevo archivo log pero no me esta funcionando. `\t arch.txt` me da el error Outfile disabled. Alguien sabe sobre este error no puedo encontrar información sobre este error.

Comment: estas seguro que tienes los privilegios suficientes para realizar esa acción? probaste utilizando usuario root?

Comment: Si tengo privilegios root

Comment: Puedes mostrarnos como tratas de crear el archivo?

Comment: Primero entro a sql con mysql -u root -p, selecciono mi tabla, y después hago  \t archivo.txt antes funcionaba pero ahora no se porque paro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que puedo leer en tu comentario (y deberías editar la pregunta y poner esa info ahí), estas ejecutando ***"\t archivo.txt"***

**Prueba esto**:

```
mysql> \T archivo.text
```

Si entras a ver la ayuda para MySQL v5.7.9

```
mysql> \h
...
notee     (\t) Don't write into outfile.
...
tee       (\T) Set outfile [to_outfile]. Append everything into given outfile.
....
```